# Add objects inside an array, attribute of singleton

Tags: php, singleton

I have a Singleton classe with an attribute `$culture = []` which is an array. To fill it, I've created a function :

```
public function addCultures($cultures){
    array_push($this->culture, $cultures);
}
```

I'm doing a foreach loop which has to add a new value each time.

```
$culture = new culture();
foreach ($fourchettes as $fourchette) {
    $culture->nom = $fourchette['nom'];
    $singleton->addCultures($culture);
}
```

My problem is that at the end, I have 3 identical data in this array. Each time it calls the function to add, it erase the previous value and replace it by the new.

First loop :
culture = ["foo"]

Second loop :
culture = ["foo2","foo2"]

Third loop:
culture = ["foo3","foo3","foo3"]

What I want is:
culture = ["foo","foo2","foo3"]

What's wrong ?

Comment: Objects are passed by reference. Your `$culture = new culture` should be inside the loop.

Comment: @JonStirling It works, thanks !